# Get speed of all the ports in Linux

Tags: linux, networking, port, health-monitoring

**Objective:**
Main objective is to the details as below (The JSON part I will do ,getting the below information using command is a problem ,from Java I can run once i get the command )

```
ether_stat_s
{
    port_name [16] : **Name** of the Port(**Can get from ifconfig -a** )
    port_udev_id;  **ID** of the port ( **No idea from where I can get ID** )
    mac_address[32] Mac address (**Ifconfig -a** )
    int speed;  // 1 = 100  Mbps/ 2 = 1Gbps/ 3 = 10 Gbps(**Only know about wlan0 and eth0**)
    uint64_t rx_pkts ( **Ifconfig -a**)
    uint64_t tx_pkts (**ifconfig -a**) 
};
```

**Work So Far:**

I have used the below command to get all the ports

command : **ifconfig -a**

```
O/p:
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 39:37:7a:bd:33:99  
          inet addr:1XX.XX.XX.X  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:b3:cc:82:a9:b1  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:64836 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:64836 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:5780566 (5.7 MB)  TX bytes:5780566 (5.7 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 39:37:7a:bd:33:99  
          inet addr:1XX.XX.XX.X  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 2601:445:4100:8bf4:76e5:43ff:fe34:c1eb/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::76e5:43ff:fe34:c1eb/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2601:445:4100:8bf4:2ca2:8b5f:c58e:8fd2/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3204378 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2060195 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3719913504 (3.7 GB)  TX bytes:583906526 (583.9 MB)
```

I am able to get Speed of **eth0** using **ethtool** (but it does not give me speed of wlan0 ,docker0,l0) ,**I can get speed of wlan0 using iwconfig,but is there any tool such as ethtool which can give me speed of all the ports in my linux .**

Also am I going in the right direction on the getting all the port information on linux (ie:Using command ifconfig -a ,or /etc/sbin/network ) .Please can anyone guide me .

Comment: Not all ports *have* speeds.

Comment: Atleast for those mentioned above

Comment: Look at the ports available on that system in `/proc/ioports` and then you can look for further details in proc for the specific ports.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin How can I get the info for those ports i want the speed,tx,rx,mac address and port name and id